# TypeError: object() takes no parameters failed error

Tags: python

What seems to be wrong with my code? I'm running into a error.

```
class Dog():

    def __init__(self, name, age):

        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def sit(self):
        """模拟小狗被命令时蹲下"""
        print(self.name.title() + " is now sitting.")

    def roll_over(self):
        """模拟小狗被命令时打滚"""
        print(self.name.title() + "rolled over!")

class Dog():

my_dog = Dog('willie', 6)

print("my dog's name is " + my_dog.name.title() + ".")

print("my dog is " + str(my_dog.age) + " years old.")
```

[image]

Comment: Wait a second, did you declare a second `class Dog():`? Don't do that!

Comment: thank you sososo much,have solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

Your problem is simply that you're redefining the dog class half-way through your code - `class Dog():` should only appear once in your program.

Since Python reads your code from top to bottom, and since the second time `class Dog():` appears, no indented code follows it, it correctly defines the `Dog` class at the top, and then redefines it to be an empty object half-way through, with no parameters: hence the wording of the error message, `TypeError: object() takes no parameters`.

### Solution

Simply remove the second `class Dog():`.

The following code should work as intended:

```
class Dog():

def __init__(self, name, age):

    self.name = name
    self.age = age

def sit(self):
    """模拟小狗被命令时蹲下"""
    print(self.name.title() + " is now sitting.")

def roll_over(self):
    """模拟小狗被命令时打滚"""
    print(self.name.title() + "rolled over!")

my_dog = Dog('willie', 6)

print("my dog's name is " + my_dog.name.title() + ".")

print("my dog is " + str(my_dog.age) + " years old.")
```

Comment: highly appreciated.